# Creating String Names for Functions in Prototype

Tags: javascript

Consider a mathematics system where different types of mathematical objects have similar operators; arrays could be added together, complex numbers could be multiplied, etc.  But these operators do not exist natively, they must be written.  Is it possible to create and use a string name in a prototype function definition?  Consider the following (intended) code:

```
var Interval = function(s,e) {
  this.a = Math.min(s,e);
  this.b = Math.max(s,e);
};

Interval.prototype["*"] = function(x,y) {
  var t = x.a*y.a;
  var u = x.a*y.b;
  var v = x.b*y.a;
  var w = x.b*y.b;
  return new Interval(Math.min(t,u,v,w), Math.max(t,u,v,w));
};

Interval.prototype["*="] = function(y) {
  var ret = this["*"](this, y);
  this.a = ret.a;
  this.b = ret.b;
};
```

Note that the particular failure I see occurs when I do something like the following:

```
var i=new Interval(1,2);
i["*="](i);
```

Then firefox complains that the second line isn't referring to a function.

There are many such functions (`"*=","-","^",...`).  It would be nice to store them by these names directly, but when I try the above it always fails, telling me things like "... is not a function" and such.  I can put in a buffer object like `Interval.prototype.ops = { "*": function(x,y) {...}};`, but that seems inelegant at best.  Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**:

This mechanism works as expected.  What does not work is attempting to call a prototyped-in function from within the constructor; for example, if the line `this["*="](this);` were to appear within the `var Interval = function(s,e) { ... };` function definition.

Comment: I get min is not a function because I don't know what type s and e are that's passed to the Interval constructor. Nor does your code show what type is returned by min and max. The code should work if you create instances: `var one = new Interval(?,?);...one['*='](two)` The problem doesn't seem to be with the prototype function but with the passed arguments to the prototype function or the returned value of min and max.

Comment: @hmr: true, my example was more abstracted than the code I included.  Corrected...

Comment: This works well for me. Please show the exact code that you tried when you got the "... is not a function" errors.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/nnvbajhb/). Executing the code you've posted correctly leaves `i` as an `Interval {a:1, b:4}`. Is there some other code? What's the exact error message?

Comment: @Bergi ok, that's better than what I was getting before.  I'll use my computer instead of my phone to ask a proper question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question resulted from a failure in my own understanding of how Javascript functions work.  In particular, I had actually attempted to call a function that was "prototyped-in" to my function from within the function constructor, in the following manner:

```
var q = function() {
  ...
  q["blather"]();
  ...
};

q.prototype["blather"] = function () {
  ...
};
```

The intended functionality in my project works as expected; my naive testing method failed and produced this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this if you avoid the prototype:

```
var i = function() { console.log("foo"); };
i["*"] = function() { console.log("bar"); };
```

And then in my console, when I ask about i or i["*"] I get:

```
> i
< function () { console.log("foo"); }
> i["*"]
< function () { console.log("bar"); }
```

I can call them successfully.

Just a heads-up though: I found these very awkward to type!

Comment: This is a good option; manually adding these functions to every object would then be a process in the constructor...  Note that I am not planning on typing these operations (most of the time), but passing them through a series of other function calls so that I don't necessarily know which operation is being invoked at a given point...

Comment: Why would you want to avoid the prototype?

Comment: @Bergi: thus my question; I was trying to do exactly the code that is (now written correctly) in my question and finding that the objects were not allowing access to the functions I created.

Comment: @abiessu: The only problem was that the code was not written correctly. I don't see a reason to avoid prototypes however, therefore my question at Blake.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with the property names you chose. When you use the brackets notation to set or get a property, the string can be virtually anything... it's just a string.

What's causing your ReferenceError is the fact that you are trying to assing a value to the `this` keyword in `this = this["*"](this, y);`.

Comment: The second example usage was added without referring to my actual code; it is the first example that fails and that I actually want to work, and the second was just another suggested usage.

Comment: The problem seems to be (at least in Firefox) that the brackets notation is not a correct accessor for the properties of the `prototype` special object; the dot notation works fine for all the code that I have.

Comment: @abiessu I can't debug anything without a full exemple to reproduce the problem...

Comment: Sorry... I think just adding `var i=new Interval(1,2); i["*="](i);` is the simplest way to have Firefox complain in the console...

Comment: @abiessu as posted in a reply to your question; the constructor would not even run because min and max are not functions of 1 and 2. So an Interval isn't even created. Your code would never even reach `i['*=']..`